# VMRC - CentOS KDE not able to output 1920x1080 (16:9) on device "Virtual1"

Tags: vmware-esxi, remote-desktop, kde

I'm using vmware Remote Console (VMRC) to remote into a few CentOS 7 machines running on EXSi 6.7.

They are all KDE Plasma and it seems like I'm unable to match the VMRC display size to my 1920x1080 monitor.

I already have increased the VRAM size to 10 MB (which should be more than sufficient for 16bit depth), but I mainly get 16:10, 4:3 or 5:4 formats and not 16:9.

The only 16:9 format I get is 1360x768 and the highest resolution suggested is 1920x1200.

Is there a proper way to get 1920x1080 working in CentOS VMRC?